# Debug application on real device

Tags: android, android-studio, usb-debugging

I followed this link https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html to debug apps from android studio on my device infinix zero 2,
Android studio does not connect with my phone, I cannot find any usb driver to my phone, any help please.

Comment: If you can't find usb drivers you will need to add the entries in the inf file yourself. To find out which ids you have to use is a bit tricky but there are guides.

Comment: Can you tell me how please, I need more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved]
I found the solution to my device infinix zero 2.
Connect phone with usb choose Built-in CD-ROM and then open my computer the phone icon will change to cd-rom open it their is install file install it and adb-interface will be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the OEM Drivers?

Available at: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html

Try to enable USB Debugging options.

Comment: This is the problem I am facing , I cannot find OME for my device or any usb device so I am looking for some thing that let me use my phone for debug